# Как соединить Laravel 5.6 и Angular 5?

Tags: веб-программирование, laravel, frontend, angular5, backend

Я хочу написать веб-приложение, использующее в качестве backend Laravel 5.6, а в качестве frontend - Angular 5.

Я знаю, что для этого с помощью Laravel надо создать RESTful API и отдавать ответы для Angular в виде JSON.

Первый вариант - я загуглил связку Angular и Laravel и по первой ссылке получил, похоже, что какую-то нужную библиотеку https://laravel-angular.io. Но неё, на мой взгляд, ужасная документация - разобраться я не смог.

Второй вариант - разместить backend в субдомене типа `api.example.com`. Но тогда возникает проблема с CORS.

В итоге, я запутался :) Подскажите, какая должна быть последовательность действий? Предпочтительнее первый вариант, так как не хочется работать с CORS

P.S. Расположить api на example.com:8000, а фронт - на example.com:3000 (что решило бы проблему CORS) не получится, т.к. приложение будет на хостинге, не на VDS.

Comment: А что не так с CORS? И нет, размещение на разных портах при одинаковых доменах и протоколах тоже нарушает Same Origin Policy и требует CORS для взаимодействия.

Comment: @D-side ого, а я этого не знал, спасибо. Ну, при CORS backend - Laravel в моём случае должен отдавать в заголовке, что он согласен принять CORS с такого домена. Где можно об этом почитать, как это настроить?

Ну и я не уверен точно, но при подключении Bootstrap они требую указывать атрибут что-то про `sameorigin`. Не будет ли CORS "ломать" подключение bootstrap?